# How are shaft motions defined in cyclic-symmetry?

Tags: fourier-analysis

When investigating the modal properties of **cyclic structures** (composed by a repetition of *N* identical sectors) such as bladed-disk assemblies, modes are often sorted by **nodal diameters** (or spatial harmonics) and **modal families**, depending on their frequency, geometrical shape and phase-shift between adjacent sectors.

It is a known phenomenon that off-axis shaft motions solely occur in 1-nodal diameter modes and that longitudinal displacements only appear in 0-nodal diameter ones. However, I have never been able to find a formal proof. Can this be shown using a purely mathematical approach?

Comment: Since this looks like mainly a math question and it hasn't been addressed after some time, I'm going to try kicking it over to Math.SE where it may be more likely to receive an answer.